# name a directory with a form input

Tags: php, forms

I have a website where you can create a chat page(stored in the folder xe5)
you type the name of the chat into an input field, and I want the name typed into the input field to be the name of the folder. In simple terms, input content=folder name.

How would I go about changing the '$dst' to whats in the input.
So far this is what I have:

```
<?php 
function recurse_copy($src,$dst) {
  $dir = opendir($src); 
  @mkdir($dst); 

  while (false !== ($file = readdir($dir))) { 
      if (( $file != '.' ) && ( $file != '..' )) { 
         if ( is_dir($src . '/' . $file) ) { 
             recurse_copy($src . '/' . $file,$dst . '/' . $file); 
         } else { 
             copy($src . '/' . $file,$dst . '/' . $file); 
         } 
      } 
  } 

  closedir($dir); 
}

$src = "./xe5";

/* dst changed by input field */
$dst = "./example";

recurse_copy($src,$dst);
?>
<form method="post" action="#">
    <input type="text" name="foldername"/>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Create Folder"/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply assign corresponding item of `$_POST` variable.

```
$dst = './'.$_POST['foldername'];
```